# Create a table in AWS athena parsing dynamic keys in nested json

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have JSON files each line of the format below and I would like to parse this data and index it to a table using AWS Athena.

```
{
  "123": {
    "abc": {
      "id": "test",
      "data": "ipsum lorum"
    },
    "abd": {
      "id": "test_new",
      "data": "lorum ipsum"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Can a table with this format be created for the above data? In the documentation, it is mentioned that `struct` can be used for parsing nested JSON, however, there are no sample examples for dynamic keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast `JSON` to map or array and transform it in any way you want. In this case you could use `map_values` and `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` to produce rows from JSON objects:

```
with test AS 
    (SELECT '{ "123": { "abc": { "id": "test", "data": "ipsum lorum" }, "abd": { "id": "test_new", "data": "lorum ipsum" } } }' AS str),
struct_like AS 
(SELECT cast(json_parse(str) AS map<varchar,
         map<varchar,
         map<varchar,
         varchar>>>) AS m
    FROM test),
flat AS 
(SELECT item
    FROM struct_like
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(map_values(m)) AS t(item))
SELECT 
  key,
  value['id'] AS id, 
  value['data'] AS data
FROM flat
CROSS JOIN unnest(item) AS t(key, value)
```

The result:

```
key id              data
abc test            ipsum lorum
abd test_new        lorum ipsum
```